# making connection code dynamic

Tags: php

the connection to database via PHP is as:

```
<?php
$DbHost = 'localhost';
$DbName = 'root';
$DbUser = 'root';
$DbPwd = '';
$dbConn = mysql_connect ($DbHost, $DbUser, $DbPwd) 
    or die ('MySQL connect failed. ' .mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($DbName,$dbConn) or die('Cannot select database. ' . mysql_error());
?>
```

Here I've hardcoded my hostname, username and password. Everytime I take my project to another machine, I've to change it.
**How can I make this connection code dynamic**?

Comment: if all you have to worry about is your db connection values when moving projects to a new machine you're in good shape.

Comment: You cannot make it more dynamically then this! Instead you can start using mysqli instead of mysql_* functions because these are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You can put machine specific information in a `settings.php` file and use

```
require_once "settings.php";
```

to get hold of the machine settings. Do this on all your machines and put the file in a specific place so your project(s) is/are able to find it.

When you move your project to another machine, it will use the corresponding `settings.php` file. (Assuming you are not copying this file as well ;) )